# Calculating Mean and Mode

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, mean, mode

I am supposed to return the mean and the mode of a given array. For the mode though, if there are two modes then I need to return the first one in the array. For example if the array was statsFinder([500, 400, 400, 375, 300, 350, 325, 300]) the output should be: [368.75, 400] since 400 occurs in the array before 300. Although I believe I am close to the solution I can't get the first occurring mode. Anyone have any idea how I could fix my code to get the first occurring mode??
Here's my solution for it:

```
function statsFinder(array) { 

let length=array.length
let sum=array.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
    return acc+curr
})
let mean=sum/length
let obj=array.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
 acc[curr]=acc[curr] ? acc[curr]+1:1
 if(acc[curr]>acc.max){ 
   acc.max=acc[curr]
 }
  return acc

},{max:1}) 

let mode=0
for(let key in obj){ 
  if (mode[key]===mode.max){ 
    mode=parseInt(key)
    }
    return [mean, mode]
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you do:

1. Scan the entire array counting the frequency of each unique value. Along the way, remember the maximum count.
2. Afterwards, scan the map of values and frequencies looking for the value which has the same count as the maximum count.

That could work, sort of, although you should fix the indentation in the second scan so that you can see why it doesn't work. You wanted this:

```js
  for(let key in obj){ 
    if (mode[key]===mode.max){ 
      mode=parseInt(key)
      return [mean, mode]
    }
  }
```

or, imho better:

```js
  for(let key in obj){ 
    if (mode[key]===mode.max){ 
      mode=parseInt(key)
      break
    }
  }
  return [mean, mode]
```

Note that it's not best practice to rely on the order of iteration of properties in a Javascript object, although it will probably work "most of the time". If you require iteration in insertion order, you should use a `Map`, if possible.

But that whole scan is silly. You could just remember the value associated with the maximum count while you count frequencies:

```
  acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? acc[curr]+1 : 1
  if (acc[curr] > acc.max) { 
    acc.maxval = curr
    acc.max = acc[curr]
  }
```

Then you know the mode without needing to search for it again, and moreover you don't have any need to convert the value back to an number.

Answer (score 0):

Just got to the same challenge and so far this is my code, hope it helps you. It's only passing 3/5 tests, so still room for improving.

```js
function statsFinder(array) {
  // Write your code here
    let sum = array.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
    const mean = sum / array.length;
    let answer = [mean];
  for(let i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
      let current = array[0];
      if(current === array[1]) {
        answer.push(current);
       break;
      } else {
        array.shift();
      }
  }
  return answer;
}

console.log(statsFinder([500, 400, 400, 375, 300, 350, 325, 300]))
```

Comment: Just a note: "Only passing 3/5 tests" simply means "broken".  You may be on the right track; I haven't really looked.  But passing *all* the tests is generally considered a minimum.